# IE9 email table bug?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html-email

I have a banner image in a table (this is email so yes, coding like 1999.) IE9 is showing space around the image despite there being 
1) cellpadding="0"
2) cellspacing="0"
3) there is no white space in the code between the  tags and the  tags
4) table width == table cell width == image width (all 600)

and the real weird kicker, when I apply hspace="0" fix, the banner goes from being aligned center (with equal 1px gaps on each side) to aligning left, despite align="center" applied to the  tag. 
(image attached)

[image]

Here's the code (image path/alt has been replaced for legal reasons)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#3ad1e2" style="color: #ffffff;"><img src="http://www.milya.ch/banner1.jpg" width="600" height="90" alt="a random kitteh banner" hspace="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="570">Some text content here</td>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem, in any web browser or email reader, using the HTML snippet posted above. Would need more HTML and possibly a screenshot showing the problem.

Comment: It may be the doctype declaration causing it to happen in IE9 -- appending original snippet above.

Comment: The screenshot and additional HTML is helpful. Still no sign of a problem though. Here's a [set of screenshots](https://litmus.com/pub/bf5ac41/screenshots) in different browsers using Litmus. Are you using a true IE9? Are you viewing it using the exact unaltered source currently shown above (not using a version of the HTML email that was forwarded, or that was copied-and-pasted into an HTML editor)?

Comment: I took the screenshot showing the 1px blue peeking out in IE9 Version: 9.0.8112.16421C0. The code posted above is the HTML file I opened in the browser.

Comment: In IE9, double-check that the Browser mode is set to "Internet Explorer 9" and that the Document mode is set to "Internet Explorer 9 standards (Page default)".

Comment: Maybe try `table td {border-collapse: collapse;}`

Comment: That didn't work, BUT, taking the banner, moving it to its own table and removing the colspan cleared up the issue. So that leads me to believe the colspan is causing the problems.

Comment: @artcase Now that you've posted the colspan stuff, it makes it a little clearer. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook colspan causes some issues if the col widths are not set in the first row. You just have to add an empty row to enforce the widths.

Not sure about IE9, but this may fix your issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="15"></td>
            <td width="570"></td>
            <td width="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#3ad1e2" style="color: #ffffff;"><img src="http://www.milya.ch/banner1.jpg" width="600" height="90" alt="a random kitteh banner" hspace="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="570">Some text content here</td>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah. Colspan is the culprit. Unfortunately, it's hard to change the group mindset in my current team to STOP using them in the first row of a table. Maybe this issue will help. Thanks to you and Matt for your responses!